# Creating multi row headers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make kind of table which has a header row then details row below it and then another header row below that and so on. It looks like this:

[image]

But I also need to borders between each cell.

Here is a jsFiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/MyeXa/2/

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Pens</h1> 

        <div class="i-info">
            <div class="row h4 i-header">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Created On
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Last Updated On
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    30/01/2013
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    04/02/2013
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="i-info">
            <div class="row h4 i-header">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    Item Number
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    Item Name
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    Item Description
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    5555
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    Pen
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    Nice pen
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="i-info">
            <div class="row h4 i-header">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Status
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Repair Status
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Good
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Fixed
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="i-info">
            <div class="row h4 i-header">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Assigned Shop
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Shop 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="i-info">
            <div class="row h4 i-header">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    LT
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    LT Pending
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    N/A 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    416 Days and 33 Minutes
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem came when I tried to add borders to separate each cell, the line is cut in the middle (see the fiddle output). I am not sure if I should change the layout or if I need to do something else with the CSS

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MyeXa/3/ . try this. it should give you a head start. although what @Anup suggested is brilliant, because tables are designed that way

Comment: Maybe stating the obvious, but is there a specific reason why you are doing this with DIVs and not using a TABLE?

Comment: @JRulle as far as I know, tables can have just one header at the top. I have no clue how to have multiple headers

Comment: You can use **table** with **th** tag replacing any **td** tag. If it's a table, no reason not to use table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `margin-bottom:0` on the H4..

```
.row .h4 {
    border-top: 1px solid #DADADA !important;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MyeXa/4/

If you want to remove all of the gaps you also need to remove the top margin, and adding padding to the cols..

http://jsfiddle.net/MyeXa/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<tr><th>column 1</th><th>column two</th><th>and column 3</th></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>more info</td><td>yet even more info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>more info</td><td>yet even more info</td></tr>
<tr><th>new column 1</th><th>column two</th><th>and column 3</th></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>more info</td><td>yet even more info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>more info</td><td>yet even more info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>more info</td><td>yet even more info</td></tr>
</table>
```

This works, now you can style it to your hearts content!